# Start Spring Batch job through JMS with Spring Cloud Dataflow

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have an application which listen to an activeMQ queue and start a Batch Job when receiving a message.

I'd like to use Spring Cloud Dataflow to provide an UI but I can't find informations on how to configure it.

Since it uses Spring Boot I should be able to replicate how my application currently works (use a REST API to make it listen to activeMQ and start job when receiving message), but I can't find anything on how to make it start the batch in Cloud Dataflow.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here.

#### Option 1: Launch your application as-is and manually send message to launch task.

Any arbitrary Spring Boot application can be launched from Dataflow (simply register it as type = "App").

Taken from https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/blob/main/spring-cloud-dataflow-docs/src/main/asciidoc/streams.adoc#register-a-stream-application:

> Registering an application by using --type app is the same as registering a source, processor or sink. Applications of the type app can be used only in the Stream Application DSL (which uses double pipes || instead of single pipes | in the DSL) and instructs Data Flow not to configure the Spring Cloud Stream binding properties of the application. The application that is registered using --type app does not have to be a Spring Cloud Stream application. It can be any Spring Boot application. See the Stream Application DSL introduction for more about using this application type.

You would have to send the task launch in your code. You can use the Dataflow REST client to do this. You can get an idea of how to do that by looking at https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/tree/main/spring-cloud-dataflow-tasklauncher/spring-cloud-dataflow-tasklauncher-sink.

#### Option 2: Use pre-built stream applications to model the same flow as your application.

The app you describe can be logically modeled as a Spring Cloud Stream application.

- There is a JMS source (provides messages to signal the need to kickoff task/batch job)
- There is a TaskLauncher sink (receives messages and kicks off the task/batch job)

This app can actually be constructed w/ little effort by using the pre-packaged applications to model this flow.

- [JMS Source](https://github.com/spring-cloud/stream-applications/tree/main/applications/source/jms-source)
- [Dataflow Tasklauncher Sink](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/tree/main/spring-cloud-dataflow-tasklauncher/spring-cloud-dataflow-tasklauncher-sink)

If you have to register these applications in the UI - they can be found at:

- maven://org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:jms-source-kafka:3.1.1
- maven://org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dataflow-tasklauncher-sink-kafka:2.9.2

Stream definition:
`jms-source | dataflow-tasklauncher-sink`

The README(s) on the above source/sinks give details about the configuration options.

#### Option 3: Custom Spring Cloud Stream app w/ function composition

The previous option would create 2 separate apps. However, if you want to keep the logic in a single app then you can look into creating a custom Spring Cloud Stream app that uses [function composition](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/stream-developer-guides/programming-models/#composing-functional-beans-in-processor-applications) and leverage the pre-built [reusable Java functions](https://github.com/spring-cloud/stream-applications#reusable-functions) that the apps in option 2 are built upon.

- [JMS Supplier](https://github.com/spring-cloud/stream-applications/blob/main/functions/supplier/jms-supplier/README.adoc#jms-supplier)
- [TaskLauncherFunction](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/blob/9158b9d18062cf0fa2f2ab2f0c94c9997dff8fd9/spring-cloud-dataflow-tasklauncher/spring-cloud-dataflow-tasklauncher-sink/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/dataflow/tasklauncher/sink/LaunchRequestConsumer.java#L77)